# Single quote variable containing a variable

Tags: shell, variables, unix

I'm using sqlplus to get data from a column which contains a shell command.

```
cmd=`sqlplus -s username/password <<EOF
        set heading off
        set trimspool on
        set termout on
        set underline off
        set linesize 2000
        set pagesize 0
        SELECT exec_cmd
          FROM cmd_table
        exit;
        EOF`
```

the exec_cmd contains a shell variable as a parameter

```
$ echo $cmd
script.sh $UP
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
connection=$1
echo "exit" | `sqlplus -s -l $connection`
```

This fails as `$connection` contains the literal string `$UP` instead of the value of `$UP`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval` to evaluate a string as a command:

```
eval "$cmd"
```

Be careful as this will run the command in the current process. It could change variables or do other unexpected things to your script. It'd be safer to explicitly invoke a subshell, which would run the command in an isolated child process:

```
sh -c "$cmd"
```

For the latter to work make sure to export `UP`.

```
UP='...'
export UP

sh -c "$cmd"
```

---

Also, get rid of the backticks around `sqlplus` in `script.sh`.

```
echo "exit" | sqlplus -s -l $connection
```